# ScenicView Javafx java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to run ScenicView as a standalong java application. I am running

```
java -jar ScenicView.jar
```

But I am getting the following output

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no attach in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.scenicview.model.attach.AttachHandlerFactory.patchAttachLibrary(AttachHandlerFactory.java:202)
at org.scenicview.model.attach.AttachHandlerFactory.initAttachAPI(AttachHandlerFactory.java:138)
at org.scenicview.ScenicView.start(ScenicView.java:167)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Platform running
Launching ScenicView v8.7.0
Startup done
Creating server
Server done
Number of running Java applications found: 4
Exception in thread "org.scenicview.model.update.RemoteVMsUpdateStrategy" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no attach in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<clinit>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:342)
at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:78)
at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:250)
at org.fxconnector.remote.RemoteConnectorImpl.getRunningJavaFXApplications(RemoteConnectorImpl.java:368)
at org.fxconnector.remote.RemoteConnectorImpl.connect(RemoteConnectorImpl.java:251)
at org.scenicview.model.update.RemoteVMsUpdateStrategy.getActiveApps(RemoteVMsUpdateStrategy.java:57)
at org.scenicview.model.update.RemoteVMsUpdateStrategy.work(RemoteVMsUpdateStrategy.java:77)
at org.fxconnector.helper.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:43)
```

ScenicView opens but never finds my JavaFX program running.

Comment: What does happen when you launch ScenicView without any other Java programs running ? (it seems with your stacktrace there are 4 ones running `Number of running Java applications found: 4` ).

Comment: What java version? what ScenicView version? On their site they have versions for java 8 and java 9.

Comment: Im Running java 8, and I have the java 8 Scenic View Version.

When I run with no java process (Ensured by killing everything returned by ps aux | grep java) it has the same two errors except it is only 1 Java application found. Which I have to assume is Scenic View itself.

Comment: Are you using the JDK's distribution of the `java` executable? I just tried launching Scenic View with the public JRE's distribution (`...\jre1.8.0_172\bin\java`) and got an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. However, if I use the JDK's distribution (`...\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\java`) Scenic View launches successfully. Scenic View must require libraries that are only shipped with the JDK.

Comment: My man. Yea i manually ran the jdk java and it launched no issue. Ok Ill post that as the answer and close it out. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the JRE version of java it caused errors. Switching to the JDK version and it worked as expected.