# Scenicview 8.7 cannot find JavaFX Application

Tags: javafx-8

Loading Scenicview.jar version 8.7 on Windows 10 (Version 10.0.16299.726) in Java 8 via cmd line:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" -Dprism.verbose=true -Djavafx.verbose=true -jar "Scenicview.jar"

I get the following error in the cmd output:

```
    Loaded C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\lib\ext\..\..\bin\jfxwebkit.dll from relative path
    Startup done
    Creating server
    Server done
   Exception in thread "org.scenicview.model.update.RemoteVMsUpdateStrategy"     java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:   sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider.tempPath()Ljava/lang/String;
        at sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider.tempPath(Native Method)
        at sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider.isTempPathSecure(WindowsAttachProvider.java:91)
        at sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider.listVirtualMachines(WindowsAttachProvider.java:75)
        at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.list(VirtualMachine.java:147)
        at org.fxconnector.remote.RemoteConnectorImpl.getRunningJavaFXApplications(RemoteConnectorImpl.java:360)
        at org.fxconnector.remote.RemoteConnectorImpl.connect(RemoteConnectorImpl.java:251)
        at org.scenicview.model.update.RemoteVMsUpdateStrategy.getActiveApps(RemoteVMsUpdateStrategy.java:57)
        at org.scenicview.model.update.RemoteVMsUpdateStrategy.work(RemoteVMsUpdateStrategy.java:77)
        at org.fxconnector.helper.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:43)
     Loading Prism common native library ...
    Loaded C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\lib\ext\..\..\bin\prism_common.dll         from relative path
        succeeded.
```

The Scenicview application runs up but does not find a JavaFX application that is also running in Java8. The searching... icon just keeps spining.

Has anyone expericenced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the JRE java.exe. If I use the JDK version it works without issue.

Duplicate of [ScenicView Javafx java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845401/scenicview-javafx-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror)